Type theory vs "Theory On Top of Logic" mantra in Set Theories
I have a question about (especially second part of) following statement following statement from wikipedia emphasizing intrinsical feature in which type theory substantially differs from set theories:

Unlike set theories, type theories are not built on top of a logic like Frege's. So, each feature of the type theory does double duty as a feature of both math and logic.

In this question I posed few days ago I tried to develop understanding & intuition for which meaning has the "a theory is build on top of a logic" phrase as a characteristic feature of set theories.
So far I understand now the first sentence one could think about a set theory in this context as a $2$-layer system with "naked" logic on the "bottom" (here logic = formal system) consisting of logical axioms, rules of inference, logical symbols we can derive new formulas of the theory independly which model we choose, one might phrase it as "the logic of the theory, which holds independently/universally how we interpret the theory".
(The "interpreting of a theory" or "give meaning" phrase  a model theorist would presumably interpret as "choosing some concrete model" :) A model theorist may feel free to correct me at that point if I'm taking nonsense at this point)
In contrast, the theory "on top" extending the logic on the bottom by "semantic part" by adding non-logical symbols axioms which - as already indicated - should be thought as "meaning/semantic" of the theory.
In model theoretic terms one could say "concrete choosen model dependent features", while the features of the "bare logic on the bottom" are model independent in the sense if we can prove a proposition on bottom level inside "logic" part, it holds in every choosen model, ie it belongs to theory's "intrinsic logic" (as fan and pun).
On should note, that in contrast to "logic on bottom" we cannot derive something coming from semantic "extension on top" as long as we haven't choosen an explicit model (which gives all these non-logical symbols living "on top" a "meaning") which highly depends of choosen model, so a "semantic" result froven in one model not need to hold in other model of the theory.
Up to now that was an admittedly rather lengthy recap how I understood (correctly?) the "a theory is build on top of a logic" concept prevailing for "classical set theories" (I don't know if there some exotic ones which try to circumvent this somehow but I don't want to discuss it here). I explained it because obviously it should be tightly connected to the question I intend to pose and maybe if what I wrote so far already contains systematical thinking error, this decisively prevents me also from finding the answer to the question I would like to pose here:
My Question is focussed primary on second quoted sentence, namely in which way Martin-Löf's type theory circumvents this "theory on top of logic" mantra  intrinsically existing in set theories?
And consequently, in which sense "a feature" (...a rather blurry term) of the type theory does "double duty" (what does this mean?) as a feature of both "math and logic" (I guess, latter means "math=theory that is on top" in contrast to "logic on bottom" in sense above)?
Sorry that the text became probably too lengthy, the question is of rather philosophic flavour mostly focussed on develop a deeper intuition for discrepance between type theory and set theories and realize it's advatages the quoted text I trying to understand presents.

Unlike theories over a logic (like second-order arithmetic or ZFC, which are theories over the first-order logic), type theories have definitions closer to natural deduction. That is, type theories have introduction and elimination rules for new types, with some computational rules. Type theories are not over a logic, but they can interpret logic in their own ways, in a form of BHK interpretation.

The statement is about a perceived difference between truth values  (e.g., $1 = 2$) and values in the universe of discourse of the theory of interest (e.g., $1$ or $1 + 2$). First-order logic makes a syntactic distinction between these two notions of value. Type-theories are usually higher-order: so truth values are just values of an appropriate type. This is just like most typed programming languages, where boolean variables are first-class citizens. First-order theories tend to be much more tractable for meta-mathematical reasoning (e.g, for results like the completeness theorem)...

... on the other hand, higher-order theories have more expressive power. You might find it useful to read about Church's simple type theory, a precursor of Martin-Löf's  type theory that comes with a pre-defined set of types and so bypasses the issue about introduction and elimination rules for types that @HanulJeon refers to (and isn't directly relevant to the issue about embracing logic in the type system).

@HanulJeon: You used a formulation I still not completely see through: "Type theories are not over a logic, but they can interpret logic in their own ways [...]". Here you strictly distinguish between to be "over a logic" and "interpreting a logic". How do you generally distinguish these two formulations precisely? So far I understand the concept behind "interpreting" in sense of BHK correctly, the "interpretation" there means just to state what should be regarded as a "legal proof", that's it? In which sense does this precisely distinguishes from the "over a logic" philosophy?

Both logic and type theory can be viewed as a set of axioms and inference rules. The axioms and formal rules for logic is for... logic (that is, for conjunctions, disjunctions, quantifiers, or so on.) Type theory usually does not have logical symbols or inference rules for them per se, but the introduction rules and elimination rules for some types behave similar to that for logical operators (e.g., conjunction and binary product in type theory.) In this sense we can interpret logic in type theory, although concepts in type theory do not mean for those in logic.

Note that a "type theory" doesn't necessarily have to have type constructions do "double duty" as a formal logic system.  There are certainly type theories where first-order logic is considered a separate part from the typing part; though they typically restrict quantifiers to be quantification over types.  (So for example, an "$\eta$ equivalence for ordered pairs" axiom of such a type theoretic system could read: if $X$ and $Y$ are types, then $\forall p : X \times Y, p = (\pi_1(p), \pi_2(p))$ is true.)

Mike Shulman explains this in detail in his blog post "From Set Theory to Type Theory". Excerpt:

[T]ype theory is not built on top of first-order logic; it does not require the imposing superstructure of connectives, quantifiers, and inference to be built up before we start to state axioms. Of course, type theory has first-order logic, which is a necessity for doing mathematics. But first-order logic in type theory is just a special case of the type-forming rules. A proposition is merely a certain type; to prove it is to exhibit an element of that type. When applied to types that are propositions, the type-forming operations of cartesian product, disjoint union, and function types reduce to the logical connectives of conjunction, disjunction, and implication; the quantifiers arise similarly from dependent sums and products. Thus, type theory is not an alternative to set theory built on the same “sub-foundations”; instead it has re-excavated those sub-foundations and incorporated them into the foundational theory itself.


+1 Correct. But this is the reason why MLTT is more difficult: traditional approach starting with elementary logic and adding successively layers of increasing conceptual complexity is pedagogically more simple.

I strongly agree with @MauroALLEGRANZA's comment, Mike Shulman is preaching to the converted. For the rest of us, there is nothing "imposing" about the usual apparatus of first-order logic while Martin-Löf type theory imposes a lot of conceptual hurdles.

Hmm, well .... Firstly, my main point was trying to answer what i understood to be the OP's question, i.e. how does one get something equivalent to FOL from type theory without using FOL? i hope that the linked post answers that question for the OP, regardless of one's subjective opinions about FOL and MLTT.

Secondly, whether it's pedagogically more simple is, i think, at least partially dependent on context. As someone with a programming background, but with no formal quals in this regard (and i also don't have formal quals in maths), FOL and MLTT have a similar level of conceptual complexity for me. And it wouldn't surprise me for this to be true for many people with at least some programming experience (which is increasingly common).

To bring the used terminology in relation with the statement from wikipedia: May I assume that by "superstructure" Schulman means what in wiki is meant by "bottom part" aka "logik/formal system" on whose "top" the theory is intended to be build? (...in realm of set theories)? Where the "stated axioms" are "on top"?

Furthermore, I'm not sure this unravels the meaning of the quoted sentence: "So, each feature of the type theory does "double duty" as a feature of both math and logic." What does this mean for any "feature" of type theory to appear as a feature of "math and logic"? In terms of "theory on top of logic" philosophy from set theory, does "math" here mean "interpreting" the top part, so "semantics"?

If yes, then this issue with "double duty" would imply for type theory that "results" obtained on the logic level ("model independent")and results obtained after interpreting inside a model ("semantical") exist for type theory on "same level"?

If what I wrote so far make sense, could it be said that an "internal feature" (...classically this would be synonymous to a true "theorem") of type theory is just a type?

Sorry, but i'm not sure i understand what you're saying/asking. For example, type theories can be the 'internal language' / syntax of categories in category theory; a type theory can provide the syntax for the semantics provided by a category. So i'd like to ask a clarifying question: Do you understand that, in type theory, proving the statement "It is true that (A and B)" is done by constructing an element of the product type "A x B"? If not, perhaps this table on Wikipedia, mapping "logic notation" to "type notation", might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory#Intuitionistic_logic

yes, so far I understand the philosophy behind "proving" in type theory, a proposition (ie in plain words, the "statement" which one intends to prove, can be regardad as a type, and "a proof" an instance of this type (similarly to an element of a set, but of course the nature is totally different; more like in cs eg $5:\text{Integer}$. So proving ($A$ and $B$) is finding an instance inside $A \times B$ as "witness" is in spirit of type theory equivalent to prove proposition( so a type) $A \times B$. And the latter is the analogon to ($A$ and $B$) in realm of type theory,

that's how I think about your question. Does it make sense?

My previous question is just about how to understand the quoted phrase "So, each feature of the type theory does "double duty" as a feature of both math and logic." Firstly, it contains certain informal terms which require clarification: Following words prevent me from understanding it. What is meaned the by a "feauture of a theory", and "math" (...in context of the quoted sentence, otherwise the latter would be a strange question =). More precisely "math" as antipode to "logic" as suggested there. Essentially my previous admittedly not well formulated question reduced to these two issues.

#Update: Or, I think I understand. Eg the "($A$ and $B$)" in "logic" has it's counterpart as a type $A \times B$, that's this "double duty" the text in refering to,right? So from this comming back the term "math" from the quoted sentence in context of type theory should be regarded as equivalent to "all what can be a type"? Does it make sense?
